# What tape to use in a damp room?

Tags: taping

I want to put up paper shades in the bathroom but it came off with my regular tape. What's the most affordable tape that will hold up in moisture-filled room? Any of the Duck brand ones?

Comment: Did You consider adhesive paper shades?

Comment: Yes, used paper shades. Got in trouble for foil.

Comment: I think they meant *self* adhesive paper shades; peel and stick. I'd think cellophane would work. What is your "regular tape"?

Comment: Where can I find self adhesive shades?  Looked everywhere...got Redishade so far but want to use the extra leftover which has no adhesive on the bottom pleats.

Comment: Do you have a link to a product like what you want to put up? I have some ideas on fastening/adhesives for different applications, but have never seen paper shades before.

Comment: I have no idea if this will work since moisture, tape and paper is just not a good combo.  For the tape, I would try using a two sided foam tape.  Just make sure the area is dry before applying.  http://www.lowes.com/pd_394734-98-110/DC_1z0yyek__?productId=3715096&pl=1

Comment: @diceless So those waterproof tapes don't do  nothing?

Comment: http://www.homedepot.ca/product/blackout-redishade/997407